# iPAD software for microscope external USB camera

Tags: android, ios

I am looking for microscope camera (AMSCOPE MU1003B USB3 10Mpx) software to run on the IPAD7 (OIS 17.1.1), and also to run on an Android smart cell phone (Note5).

*To be clear, the IOS and Android solutions are most probably two separate software products, not one product that would run on both OSs.*

I have Spoken with Logitech, Apple, AMSCOPE, Google, Bard, etc. looked and can not find any. I am told it does not exist. Again, I do not believe it. Is anyone aware of any such software that works?

Comment: I verified the camera does not use proprietary hardware or custom USB pin outs. Both  the camera and AMSCOPE software is open source. Nothing held back or proprietary. What software product is out there that will run this camera on an iPad7 running OIS 17.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 17 does support external USB webcams. Whenever I connect a USB camera, apps can use that. Also my USB microscope camera works fine. You might want to check with FaceTime first if yours shows up as well. After that use any Video App that shows the camera's picture.
This of course only can be used for viewing. Measuring, settings, etc. do not work.

Comment: What mod IPAD are you working with? 
The IPAD7 I am working with will run 17.1.1 (already upgraded) but uses lightning connector. Have tried several Lightning/USB converters. None I have tried will allow recognition of the Web camera. Do you know of a Lightning to USB or to WI-Fi converter that will work on an IPAD7? Thank you.